# Is there a list of build-in code snippet references in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I noticed that `$selected$` and `$end$` is used a lot when working with code snippets in Visual Studio, but is there a list of all the references that can be used, e.g. can I get the name of the current file that I'm working on with something like `$filename$` or do I need to use the ExpansionProvider and ExpansionFunction classes?

As a note I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express but I don't think it would be that much different from other versions.

Comment: There's nothing like that.  $selected$ and $end$ are predefined, any other ones must match a `<Literal>` or `<Object>` element in the snippet.  Functions are very limited and specific to the C# IDE.  Reference [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242312.aspx).

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for your reply. I guess it is very limited unless you can define it as part of the schema.

Comment: Hi Hans I just re-discovered this question on my profile. If you don't mind posting your comment as an answer I can credit you properly :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments by @HansPassant there are only a limited number of keywords that can be used. Check the MSDN article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242312.aspx